# Is a proof with a bunch of variables like this valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I was wondering if it is generally proper to make proofs in the following style:

> prove: IF a ≡ b(mod m) THEN a + c ≡ b + c(mod m).

> a ≡ b(mod m) means that *a = km+r* and *b = jm+r*. (both r's being the same)

> *a+c then would equal km+c+r* and likewise *b+c would equal jm+c+r*

> if we rewrite c to be of the same form, some multiple of *m* plus some constant, say R then:

> c = lm + R

> thus *a+c = km+(lm+R)+r = (k+l)m + (R+r)* and *b+c = jm+(lm+R)+r = (j+l)m + (R+r)*

> and since the modulo function returns the remainder after dividing *m*, a + c ≡ b + c(mod m) since *(R+r)* = *(R+r)*

I think this makes sense (point out any mistakes if there are any) but is it even proper to have so many variables that aren't really used as long as they are used to illustrate something (such as a value being able to be represented as a multiple of some number plus some constant as I do here)?

Comment: See [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). For example, instead of "a ≡ b(mod m)" you should write "$a\equiv b \pmod{m}$" by writing "`$a\equiv b \pmod{m}$`".

Comment: "a ≡ b(mod m) means that a = km+r and b = jm+r. (both r's being the same)"  Okay, a *real* pet peeve of mine is that that $a\equiv b\pmod m$ means that *THERE IS AN INTEGER* $k$ and and integer $r$ so that that $a = km+r$.  It does *NOT* mean that $a = km +r$ because we have no idea what $k$ is.  You can't bring it in without any introduction.  Stating $a = km + r$ implies $k$ is known.  But what if $a \ne km+r$ what if $a = 7m + r$ and $k$ *doesn't* equal $7$.  or what if $a = (k+1)m + r$.  What then?

Comment: No need to bring in $r$.  $a \equiv b \pmod m$ means there is an integer $k$ so that $a = km + b$.  ... which makes the proof simpler.  $a = km + b$ so $a + c = km + b+c$ so $a+c \equiv \pmod m$.  Nothing more to be said.  No need to find there common remainder.

Comment: Of course if you want to be a stickler then actual definition of $a \equiv b \pmod m$ is that $m$ divides $a-b$.  And as $a-b = (a+c) - (b+c)$ it follows that $m$ divides $(a+c) -(b+c)$ so $a+c \equiv b+c \pmod m$. (wuestenfux' answer).

Comment: @fleablood Isn't it implied that for *a*, *k* and *r* are solutions to the equation that make this relation true. I supposed that for every integer *a* there are unique solutions (k and r) that make the relation true, is this false?

Comment: "since the modulo function "  Advice:  Get out of thinking in terms of remainder function or modulo *function*.  There is nothing significant about finding the "remainder" the smallest positive value less than $m$.  $a \pmod m$ *isn't* a number $r$ and shouldn't be thought of as such.  $a \equiv b \pmod m$ is a statement about some equivalence $a$ and $b$ have in common.  There is no need to talk about the remainder $r; 0 \le r < m$ that they both have in common.  And $a\pmod m$ should *not* be thought of as a *function* that returns $r$.

Comment: "Isn't it implied that for a, k and r are solutions to the equation that make this relation true"  It's implied that there *ARE* solutions for the equation, and you can *name* them $k$ and $r$ if you like.  But if you don't *introduce* $k$ and $r$ first the statement "$a\equiv b \pmod m$ means $a = km+r$ is meaningless.  Suppose $a= 34$ and $b =42$ and $m=8$ then it is true that $a \equiv b \pmod 8$ and that $a = 4*m + 2$  but it does *not* mean that $a = km +r$ because we don't know that $k = 4$ or that $r =2$.  If $k= 4785493758439$ and $r =974835$ then that is certainly *not* true.

Comment: @fleablood Interesting. Is ur advice basically to not think about this function so literally? Analogous to how in early arith. one might conceptualize the operations of mult. as repeated add., div. as repeated sub., or exp. as repeated mult., whereas these very same elementary conceptualizations might very well hinder how they understand extensions of these ideas and later abstractions or r u getting at something different? u r essentally saying to think about $a\equiv b \pmod{m}$ as some equvalence relation between a and b via some function with such and such properties, right?

Comment: @fleablood P.S. — Please don't mind the abbreviations in the above comment and thank you for communicating your math pet peeves so I can try to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a shorter proof would be like this.

If $a\equiv b\mod m$, then $m$ divides $a-b$.

Then $m$ divides $(a+c)-(b+c) = a-b$ and so $a+c\equiv b+c\mod m$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing this means that my proof was valid? In any case, I will strive to keep them short.

Comment: Indeed. But it ended up with (R+r) = (R+r) which need not be a remainder mod m.